# Interfacing with AirPods on IOS

Tags: ios, swift, audio, bluetooth, hardware

I am trying to write an IOS app that will take left and right audio from connected AirPods' microphones, and play back the sound in real time, after some processing.

I haven't found any information on how to connect to, and talk to the AirPods after much searching on Apple's developer sites, and a few related but unhelpful StackOverflow questions.

How do you connect to these devices, and what's a good place to get information regarding the technology?
Thanks.

Comment: I'd have thought AirPods are essentially "just another" bluetooth device. I own a pair, and I have no idea what you mean by *"will take left and right audio **from** connected AirPods"*. Audio is pushed **to** them, not taken *from* them. Please explain what you mean by this.

Comment: @dfd, AirPods have onboard microphones. I am trying to find out how to get the stereo audio they record.